# On the fly/Dynamic measuring not working on Measurement Widget with different Basemap

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, measurements, widget

I am developing an application with OS Open Carto Map as a Basemap and I have added a Measurement widget in the app.
The measurement widget works fine for when the points are clicked for distance and area, but it doesn't calculate the distance on the fly/dynamically (before you set/click the second point) as in this ESRI [Demo](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=widget_measurement).

Here is the code:

```
<script>
var map;
require([
    "dojo/dom",
    "esri/basemaps",
    "esri/Color",
    "dojo/keys",
    "dojo/parser",
    "esri/config",
    "esri/sniff",
    "esri/map",
    "esri/SnappingManager",
    "esri/dijit/Measurement",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
    "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer",
    "esri/tasks/GeometryService",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
    "esri/dijit/BasemapLayer", "esri/dijit/Basemap",
    "esri/dijit/Scalebar",
    "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
    "dijit/TitlePane",
    "dijit/form/CheckBox",
    "dojo/domReady!"
  ], function(
    dom, esriBasemaps, Color, keys, parser,
    esriConfig, has, Map, SnappingManager, Measurement, FeatureLayer, SimpleRenderer, GeometryService, SimpleLineSymbol, SimpleFillSymbol,
    BasemapLayer, Basemap
  ) {
    parser.parse();

    esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/proxy/";
    esriConfig.defaults.io.alwaysUseProxy = false;

    //This service is for development and testing purposes only. We recommend that you create your own geometry service for use within your applications
    esriConfig.defaults.geometryService = new GeometryService("https://utility.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");

    var bounds = new esri.geometry.Extent({
        "xmin":1393.0196,
        "ymin":13494.9764,
        "xmax":671196.3657,
        "ymax":1230275.0454,
        "spatialReference":{"wkid":27700}
    });

    var lods = [  
        {"level" : 0, "scale" : 5000000, "resolution" : 1322.9193125052918},   
        {"level" : 1, "scale" : 2500000, "resolution" : 661.4596562526459},   
        {"level" : 2, "scale" : 1000000, "resolution" : 264.5838625010584},   
        {"level" : 3, "scale" :  500000, "resolution" : 132.2919312505292},   
        {"level" : 4, "scale" :  250000, "resolution" : 66.1459656252646},   
        {"level" : 5, "scale" :  100000, "resolution" : 26.458386250105836},   
        {"level" : 6, "scale" :   50000, "resolution" : 13.229193125052918},   
        {"level" : 7, "scale" :   25000, "resolution" : 6.614596562526459},   
        {"level" : 8, "scale" :   10000, "resolution" : 2.6458386250105836},   
        {"level" : 9, "scale" :    5000, "resolution" : 1.3229193125052918},   
        {"level" :10, "scale" :    2500, "resolution" : 0.6614596562526459},   
        {"level" :11, "scale" :    1000, "resolution" : 0.26458386250105836},   
        {"level" :12, "scale" :     500, "resolution" : 0.13229193125052918},   
        {"level" :13, "scale" :     250, "resolution" : 0.066145965625264591},   
        {"level" :14, "scale" :     100, "resolution" : 0.026458386250105836},   
    ];  

    var myLayer = new BasemapLayer({
       url: "https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/qHLhLQrcvEnxjtPr/arcgis/rest/services/OS_Open_Carto_2/MapServer"
    });
    var myBasemap = new Basemap({
       layers: [myLayer],
       title: "OS Open Carto",
        //thumbnailUrl: "https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/86de95d4e0244cba80f0fa2c9403a7b2/info/thumbnail/tempimagery.jpg"
    });

    map = new Map("map", {
        extent: bounds,
        basemap: myBasemap,
        zoom: 1,
        lods: lods,
        showLabels : true
    });

    var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id ="measurementDiv";
        document.getElementById("measureDiv").appendChild(div);


    var measurement = new Measurement({
      map: map
    }, dom.byId("measurementDiv"));
    measurement.startup();

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that option is disable when your map is in a different coordinate system that Web Mercator and Geographics.

If you think about it, it actually make sense. I don't think it would be optimum to query the geometry service on each mouse move event.

When you don't use the above mention coordinate systems, it only query the geometry service on each point added.

You can check that by listening to `measure` property change like this,

```
on(measurement, 'measure', function(e) { console.log(e); });
```